# Is there a way in scala using functionality from super class in mixed in trait

Tags: scala

I have the following classes/traits setup:

```
class RestService extends EntityReader[UserEntity]
  with EntityReaderExtension {

  def serveSomething() = {...}

}

trait EntityReader[EntityType <: StoredEntity] extends RestHelper {
    protected def read(id:UUID): Option[EntityType] = {
        // Read by id
    }
}


trait EntityReaderExtension {
    def serveExtensionMethod(id:UUID) = {
        // val entity = read(id) match {...}
        // copy values to other entity and serve
    }
}
```

Is there a way i can use the method from trait EntityReader in trait EntityReaderExtension without extending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is an [explicitly typed self reference](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/explicitly-typed-self-references.html).

```
trait EntityReaderExtension { self: EntityReader[_] =>
  def serveExtensionMethod(id:UUID) = {
    val entity = self.read(id) match {...}
  }
}
```

Comment: My comment was replying to someone else's comment, who has since deleted it. I've now deleted my response. Let's just pretend none of this ever happened :)